# Parallelism of simple math

Tags: r, multithreading, math, openmp, shared-memory

I have to perform a lot of element-wise arithmetic and special function mathematical operations on a large numeric matrix (e.g. 100,000 x 20,000) in `R`, including:

`exp`, `log`, `lbeta`, `digamma`, `plogis` (logistic function: 1/[1+exp(-a*x)]), and `/, *, +, -`

Looking into the [math library C source code for `R`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk/src/nmath), there are essentially no `#pragma omp` compiler directives to take advantage of shared-memory multi-threaded parallelism. Specialized packages for fast math operations in `R` like `[Rfast][2]` do not have `#pragma omp` directives for multi-threaded special functions either.

Similarly, as far as I understand, matrix algebra libraries like BLAS and LAPACK are for matrix operations (e.g. factorizations), not element-wise operations.

I am hoping to run the `R` script on AWS to speed up the operations using e.g. 72 or 96 core servers.

Do I really have to make my own copies of the R math library C source code just to add a few `#pragma omp` directives to take advantage of OpenMP parallelism in R?

I can't believe simple parallelism like this does not already exist in `R` in the `base` or in a simple math library package.

Comment: The [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support) mentions that *"some toolchains ... have no OpenMP support at all, not even `omp.h`"*. That's just a symptom, not an answer to your question. There is considerable documentation on doing your own things (e.g., C/C++ and Rcpp) using OpenMP, though again likely not what you want. It's been a long-standing question (R and threading), with not a resounding fix. (I don't have enough time to post a PR, I too was hoping somebody else would :-)

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans. It is not a big deal to do it myself - I could copy the `R` source and throw in some directives. But the lack of something so simple makes me wonder if there is something less-than-obvious about this...

Comment: Yes ... my guess is that it doesn't compile as cleanly on all supported platforms. One might suggest (it has crossed *my* mind) that variable support by-platform might be okay (e.g., *"you'll get better performance on X, Y, and Z, but not W due to lack of perfect OpenMP support ... but the results are all identical"*). I don't think you're the first to ask/ruminate over this, but I believe we "just need somebody to do it" (and then convince R Core that the suggested solution should be the norm).

Comment: FYI, the [R-3.6.0-beta NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-3.6.0beta.html) says: *"Installation on a Unix-alike tries harder to link to the pthread library where required (rather than relying on OpenMP to provide it: configuring with --disable-openmp was failing on some Linux systems)"*. Another consideration would be checking to make sure that the linux package maintainers are allowing this new stuff (only a factor if you do not compile it yourself, admittedly a daunting task). (I have not checked, just a thought.)

Comment: Good find @r2evans ! 
But even if `R` compiles with `pthread` or `openmp` support, the math functions themselves (looking at the C source code) have no `pragma` directives, so they would still be computed serially when applied element-wise to a matrix, right?

Comment: You're digging into the source more than I am, cmo. Sorry, I wonder if other devs/maintainers/r-cores would be able to comment. Over to you if you want to invite by-name, such as Dirk Eddelbuettel, the maintainer of debian R packages who often has insightful comments about things like this.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel

Comment: not sure how to invite by name to the SO thread...

Comment: (Spaces are not usually used in ampersand-references, so your comment was looking for a user named "Dirk".) It doesn't always work well: some ignore by-name requests to jump into a conversation, some just don't frequent it timely-enough and it falls by the wayside. Some (often those well-known as maintainers and contractors of services that these questions ask about) specifically request not doing this, I don't know how Dirk feels about the subject.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: I remember Luke Tierney's `pnmath` package at http://www.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/experimental/ that, I thought, would become an extension to R. It seems to be the answer to the question but the last version is 2012. Is this now available somewhere else?